# Library for Date Ranges for Moment JS or ISO string

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, date-range, human-readable

Is there a JS library that can display date ranges in human readable format from MomentJS objects?

E.g. Accept two `MomentJS objects` or `ISO strings` and instead of displaying:

`2013-02-04T22:44:30.652Z - 2013-02-09T22:44:30.652Z`

intelligently display something like this:

`February 9th-12th`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I just found it -

Twix.js looks like it will do the job: http://isaaccambron.com/twix.js/